Fundamental group of a smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $X_{\mathbb{R}}$ be a smooth, projective surface over $\mathbb{R}$. Then its complexification, $X$, is a smooth complex projective surface.
$X_\mathbb{R}$ is a manifold, so we can talk about its pointed fundamental group, $\pi_1(X_\mathbb{R}, x)$, for a fixed $x\in X_{\mathbb{R}}$. On the other hand, it should be possible to define some sort of algebraic analog of $\pi_1(X_\mathbb{R})$, where one considers only loops given by intersections of $X_\mathbb{R}$ with algebraic curves in $X$.
Here's a first attempt to define such a group: Let
$\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of irreducible curves in $X$ passing through $x$. Then for each $\alpha \in \mathcal{C}$, $\alpha\cap X_{\mathbb{R}}$ is a finite union of curves in $X_{\mathbb{R}}$; let $\alpha_x$ denote the one passing through $x$. Let $$S = \{[\alpha_x] : \alpha\in\mathcal{C}\},$$ where $[\alpha_x]$ denotes the equivalence class of $\alpha_x$ up to pointed homotopy at $x$. Clearly, $S$ is a subset of $\pi_1(X, x)$. We let $\hat \pi_1(X, x)$ denote subgroup of $\pi_1(X, x)$ generated by $S$.
In some very simple cases, like $X = \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i]\times \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $X_\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, we actually have $\hat \pi_1(X, x) = \pi_1(X, x)$. Indeed, the curves $\{x = 0\}, \{y = 0\}$ intersect $X_\mathbb{R}$ in loops generating $\pi_1(X_\mathbb{R})$. But this is a very simple case, and I'm wondering if one can expect these groups to be equal in general
Does this group $\hat \pi_1(X_\mathbb{R})$ have a name? It seems pretty natural, so I'd imagine it has been studied.
Any comments or pointers to references would be greatly appreciated!

What do you mean by "algebraic curves in $X$" if $X$ is only a complex surface? Do you mean that $X$ is also an algebraic surface? Is it clear that the generic algebraic surface contains any algebraic curves?

@QiaochuYuan Thanks for the comment - I've edited the question. For simplicity, I'll assume $X$ to be an algebraic surface.

@QiaochuYuan To address your second questions: if $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a smooth complex projective variety and $L\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a hyperplane in general position, then $L\cap X$ is a projective variety of dimension $1$ and thus a curve, no?

First of all, $X_{\mathbb R}$ need not be connected. Secondly, even if $X_{\mathbb R}$ is connected, its intersections with complex curves need not be connected. Also, are you still going to use pointed homotopy as your equivalence relation? You should think a bit more about your definition of $\hat\pi$.

You're right; I've edited the question with a more precise definition.

Making a trivial 1-character edit to bump your post isn't cool. It would be better to make a more substantial edit or add a bounty.

the deleted exclamation mark reflects my decreased confidence that the question has a satisfying answer @HankScorpio ;)
